# Grails webdriver installation error

Tags: grails, webdriver, grails-plugin

I'm trying to install webdriver to for integration testing on Grails 2.0 but I always get this error and the installation is incomplete.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/RegexExpression

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused, because Groovy 1.8 deprecated the RegexExpression class.
What you can do is download the GMetrics library:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmetrics/files/gmetrics-0.4/

I had the same problem, and with that library (GMetrics-0.4.jar) added to the project fixed the problem.